# SQLite query across multiple ranges obtained from other table

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need help with writing an sqlite3 query. EDIT - There is one lap to many data and the data for a lap is defined by the start_time and end_time.

```
--laps table--
_id
session_id
lap
lap_time
start_time
finish_time
<other columns>

--data table--
_id
session_id
time
rpm
<other columns>
```

I'd like to get the lap, lap_time, min(rpm), avg(rpm) and max(rpm) for each lap (i.e. data.time > laps.start_time && data.time < laps.finish_time) for a given session (laps.session_id = data.session_id. All the time fields are integer (nanoseconds) and the rpm field is real.

I can already do it by querying laps, lopping over the result set and querying data for each lap, but I'd like to do it with one query. I have no idea how to write the join and conditions so any help is appreciated.

EDIT - INEFFICIENT SOLUTION

```
String query = "SELECT l.lap_num, l.lap_time, " +
            "(SELECT min(d."+columnName+") FROM logged_data d WHERE d.time > l.start_time AND d.time < l.finish_time AND d.session_id = l.session_id), " +
            "(SELECT avg(d."+columnName+") FROM logged_data d WHERE d.time > l.start_time AND d.time < l.finish_time AND d.session_id = l.session_id), " +
            "(SELECT max(d."+columnName+") FROM logged_data d WHERE d.time > l.start_time AND d.time < l.finish_time AND d.session_id = l.session_id) " +
            "FROM laps l WHERE l.session_id = " + session_id + ";";
```

I'll add this as the answer unless anybody can rewrite it so it won't have to perform 3 queries per lap.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can `join` the tables together and use `group by` with multiple aggregates:

```
select l.lap, l.lap_time, min(d.rpm), avg(d.rpm), max(d.rpm)
from laps l
    join data d on l.session_id = d.session_id
group by l.lap, l.lap_time
```

Comment: The select and the join are correct but data for each lap should be grouped by a time range from start_time to end_time. If I could conveniently show tables of data it would be clearer. I should have mentioned that its a one-to-many relationship (1 lap, many data).